# Como fazer o Bootstrap 4 ter o visual do Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Supondo que eu esteja usando o Bootstrap 3 em um projeto e queira atualizá-lo para passar a usar a versão 4, mas mantendo o visual do Bootstrap 3 (botões com gradientes, sombras, etc).

Existe alguma forma de fazer isto de maneira fácil? O pré-processador SASS tem alguma configuração para ajudar nisto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A própria Bootstrap disponibiliza uma documentação oficial completa para fazer a migração da versão 3 para a 4 como vc pode consultar aqui!

https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/migration/

Exite uma série de diferenças entre uma versão e outra, entre elas a o Grid que na V3 era baseado em `Float` e na V4 é em `Flex`, além disso na V3 ele era em `LESS` agora é em `SCSS`. O JavaScript de uma versão para a outra tb mudou, e o `bootstrap.js` da V3 não funciona na V4 e vice-versa, inclusive na V3 nem existia o `popper.js`, já na V4 ele praticamente é obrigatório caso vc queira que a `navbar`, `dropdowns` e `collapses` funcionem corretamente...

[Aqui tem uma lista com mais de 30 mudanças entre uma versão e a outra](https://www.quackit.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_4/differences_between_bootstrap_3_and_bootstrap_4.cfm)

---

**Sobre deixar um com a aparência do outro**

Sim, pode ser possível sim manter a aparência da V3 na V4, mas acredito que vai ser preciso tanto *override* que nem valeria a pena migrar apenas pelo "aspecto visual". A versão 4 é baseada em `REM` e não e `PX`, só isso já seria uma chatura de ficar calculando, e como um era em `LESS` e o outra é `SCSS` vc teria que fazer uma série de recompilações...

Comparação entre o Form padrão da **`V3` x `V4`**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem acima vc pode reparar que a `label` tem negrito, o espaçamento lateral do `container` da V4 é maior, assim como o `padding` no `input` e o espaçamento vertical entre um elemento e outro.

Logicamente que vc pode contornar isso pelo CSS, mas será que vale a pena? Vc basicamente teria que ir no SCSS e alterar os valores em `REM` para `PX` na mesma medida da versão 3 e depois compilar o `bootstrap.css`, além dessas mudanças básicas vc teria que alterar o tema das **Cores** etc...

Veja que vc precisaria mudar o valor das variáveis das cores, pois elas não são exatamente iguais...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

`OBS:` Segundo a própria **Bootstrap ainda em 2019 deve ser lançada a Versão 5**, então caso vc esteja pensando em migrar recomendo que aguarde mais uns meses. Fonte no Blog oficial deles: https://blog.getbootstrap.com/#branches-hugo-and-jquery

Comment: Ótima explicação e ótima sugestão sobre a validade de migrar de versão.

Comment: @ThiagoKrempser pois eh a versão 5 deve ser lançada ainda esse ano, melhor aguardar um pouco etc... Valeu a força 